# onsubmit function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onsubmit

Why is it saying that I have not defined my function? Is it because I have placed my function inside a document ready function? - Maybe I have to mention that I want to use this function to prevent submitting if my statement is not true.

my form tag in html:

```
<form class="text-left" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return myFunction();">
```

below is script(this script is in my head section) :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //the number generators and sum of the two numbers
    var numberOne = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
    var numberTwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var sum = numberOne + numberTwo;

    //write the math question to the div
    document.getElementById("captchaOutput").innerHTML = numberOne+ " og " +numberTwo;
    //alert(sum);

    function myFunction(){
        var humanInput = $('#captchaInput').val();

        if(humanInput == sum){

            $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "inline")
            $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "red");
             return false;
        }
             $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "none")
        $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "");
        return true;       
    }  
});
```

Comment: why are you mixing javascript and jquery?

Comment: Use the global object to declare it!

Comment: Just add `window.myFunction = function () {` instead of `function myFunction () {` and it should work!

Comment: @Mivaweb That's a very poor way to phrase that. jQuery *is* JavaScript, they coexist and should be *'mixed'*. The better question is 'Why are you mixing inline JavaScript with non globally scoped event handlers?'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> it because i have placed my function inside a document ready function?

Yes. Function declarations are (like `var` statements) scoped to the function they are declared within.

---

If you want to use `myFunction` as a global then move it, and the variables it depends on, out of the anonymous function you declare it with in.

---

Alternatively, you could explicitly create a global that references it:

```
window.myFunction = myFunction
```

---

The best solution, however, is to not use a global in the first place.

Remove the `onsubmit` attribute and bind your event handlers with JavaScript instead.

```
$('form').on('submit', myFunction);
```

Make sure you capture the event object:

```
function myFunction(e){
```

Then prevent the default form submission behaviour if you don't want it to submit:

```
$("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "red");
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `myFunction` is defined within the scope of the `$(document).ready` and is **not visible** outside. Define it outside along with its dependant variables

```
//the number generators and sum of the two numbers
var numberOne = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var numberTwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var sum = numberOne + numberTwo;
$(document).ready(function() {
    //write the math question to the div
    document.getElementById("captchaOutput").innerHTML = numberOne + " og " + numberTwo;
    //alert(sum);
});

function myFunction() {
    var humanInput = $('#captchaInput').val();

    if (humanInput == sum) {

        $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "inline")
        $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "red");
        return false;
    }
    $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "none")
    $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "");
    return true;
}
```

**Update**

Remove the inline `onsbumit` for the form and use `on()` like below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //the number generators and sum of the two numbers
    var numberOne = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
    var numberTwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var sum = numberOne + numberTwo;

    //write the math question to the div
    document.getElementById("captchaOutput").innerHTML = numberOne+ " og " +numberTwo;
    //alert(sum);

    $('form').on('submit', function(){
        var humanInput = $('#captchaInput').val();

        if(humanInput == sum){

            $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "inline")
            $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "red");
             return false;
        }
             $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "none")
        $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "");
        return true;       
    });  
});
```

Comment: @MartinNielsen, glad it did. But I suggest you follow Quentins answer and bind with jquery `.on('submit')` instead

Comment: @MartinNielsen, if you dont know how, let me or Quentin know so we can provide more detail

Answer (score 1):

Try using `window` Object here:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //the number generators and sum of the two numbers
    var numberOne = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
    var numberTwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var sum = numberOne + numberTwo;

    //write the math question to the div
    document.getElementById("captchaOutput").innerHTML = numberOne+ " og " +numberTwo;
    //alert(sum);

    window.myFunction = function () {
        var humanInput = $('#captchaInput').val();

        if(humanInput == sum){

            $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "inline")
            $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "red");
             return false;
        }
             $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "none")
        $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "");
        return true;       
    }  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var sum = 0;
    $( document ).ready(function() {

            //the number generators and sum of the two numbers
            var numberOne = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
            var numberTwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            sum = numberOne + numberTwo;

            //write the math question to the div
            document.getElementById("captchaOutput").innerHTML = numberOne+ " og " +numberTwo;
            //alert(sum);


        });

       function myFunction(){
                var humanInput = $('#captchaInput').val();

                if(humanInput == sum){

                    $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "inline")
                    $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "red");
                     return false;
                }
                     $("#captcha_service_err").css("display", "none")
                $("#captchaInput").css("border-color", "");
                return true;       
            }
```

Comment: This won't work, because `myFunction()` still tries to use `sum`.