# javascript form validation always returns true even when condition matches and should returns false

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a javascript form validation based on [**Vikrant**](https://jsfiddle.net/r2ykavh8/9/)'s script on jsfiddle.

I have made my own script on jsfiddle too [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/zgw94xn9/) it is pretty similar to his code but for some reason, the alert never triggers, the form is submitted even though it should not be.

this is happening in my localhost too.

also here is the code :

```js
function FormValidasi() {
  if (document.getElementById('cabang').value == "tor") {
    alert("Mohon pilih cabang nya");
    return false;
  } else if (document.getElementById('tipe').value == "tor") {
    alert("Mohon pilih tipenya");
    return false;
  }
  return (true);
}
```

```html
<form name="Formulir" method="post" action="2013.php" onsubmit="return FormValidasi();">
  <input type="text" name="cabang" id="cabang" placeholder="Input cabang">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="tipe" id="tipe" placeholder="Input Tipe">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

so if I type `"tor"` inside both field, or just one of the field, the script should be `returning false` and prevent the form submitting? but the form is submitted even if I typed `"tor"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for not working your code is the line you've coded here as `return (true);` The code execution for your JS is check the `IF` conditions and **return only one** output from there. From the line where you always `return true` means script executes the IF statement but ultimately `return true` even you have an error on your input fields.

```js
function FormValidasi() {
  if (document.getElementById('cabang').value == "tor") {
    alert("Mohon pilih cabang nya");
    return false;
  } else if (document.getElementById('tipe').value == "tor") {
    alert("Mohon pilih tipenya");
    return false;
  }  
}
```

```html
<form name="Formulir" method="post" action="2013.php" onsubmit="return FormValidasi();">
  <input type="text" name="cabang" id="cabang" placeholder="Input cabang">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="tipe" id="tipe" placeholder="Input Tipe">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Update 1**

Reasonable argument has been made by 2 users and i have update the snippet to avoid getting error as below.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: FormValidasi is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

This can be avoid from making the form submit validation function as global function.

`window.FormValidasi = FormValidasi;`

**Updated code:**

```js
window.FormValidasi = FormValidasi;

function FormValidasi() {
  if (document.getElementById('cabang').value == "tor") {
    alert("Mohon pilih cabang nya");
    return false;
  } else if (document.getElementById('tipe').value == "tor") {
    alert("Mohon pilih tipenya");
    return false;
  }  
}
```

```html
<form name="Formulir" method="post" action="2013.php" onsubmit="return FormValidasi();">
  <input type="text" name="cabang" id="cabang" placeholder="Input cabang">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="tipe" id="tipe" placeholder="Input Tipe">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Read more about the function error on [onsubmit function is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803497/onsubmit-function-is-not-defined)

**Update 2**

Thanks to giving a thought on looking at the code again. The OP had the function correctly defined. As the problem was his function not executing properly was entirely due to js mishap. It can be avoided by making the function `global`.

Comment: Sure. the snippet works here and it should meet your expectations. :)

Comment: No problem. Happy coding to you bud. :)

Comment: Why does this happen?  why would the `return false` statements *not* work?  If the `if` statement evaluates to `true`, the code within the controlled block should execute, including the `return false` so that the `return true` is not reached.

Comment: `function FormValidasi() {

            if(true) {
                alert("enter something valid");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
}  //when this is run, it returns "false".

Comment: @FKEinternet it was poor coding. `return false` overridden by `return(true)` line

Comment: I would expect `return false` to return from the ***function***, not from the nested `if` block

Comment: and I thought @FKEinternet is correct. It should not reach `return (true)`. Moreover, my browser shows error `FormValidasi is not defined`.

Comment: @appleapple read about function error in here. [onsubmit function is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803497/onsubmit-function-is-not-defined)

Comment: Update the snippet to accommodate the error. Fiddle should work now. :)

Comment: So, the problem was ***not*** the `return true` statement, it was an ***undefined function*** that caused the form to always submit.  The **`return false`** statements ***do*** trump the `return true`, as expected, and the `return true` statement *should* be in place so the function is always returning a value.

Comment: [you new version does not work either](https://jsfiddle.net/va8wnbg4/2/), I would say is a bug or something of jsfiddle

Comment: @lnuka oh yes, well, it's pretty strange (at least to me) though. And would you like to enplane why the Vikrant's version does work?

Comment: The first paragraph in this answer is totally false, do not be deceived by it!  In particular, "From the line where you always return true means script executes the IF statement but ultimately return true even you have an error on your input fields." is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the previously accepted answer and its comments, the correct code should be:

Javascript

```
window.FormValidasi = FormValidasi;

function FormValidasi() {
  if (document.getElementById('cabang').value == "tor") {
    alert("Mohon pilih cabang nya");
    return false;
  } else if (document.getElementById('tipe').value == "tor") {
    alert("Mohon pilih tipenya");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="Formulir" method="post" action="2013.php" onsubmit="return FormValidasi();">
  <input type="text" name="cabang" id="cabang" placeholder="Input cabang">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="tipe" id="tipe" placeholder="Input Tipe">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The problem was ***not*** the last line of the function being executed to always return `true` as stated in the first paragraph of the accepted answer, but rather that there was a *coding error preventing the function from being executed* in the first place.